# Shopping cart empty after logging in from OneStepCheckout page in magento

Tags: magento, authentication, checkout, onestepcheckout

I have multiple websites pointing to the same checkout page , 
but when i try to order from a website suppose SITE B,
it get's redirected to onestepcheckout in SITE A which is ok , 
but when a customer tries to login, it redirects to "shopping cart empty" page
and customer is not logged in.but if the customer tries to login to the SITE A again 
the cart has the products in it.

Can anybody please help me figure out what might be the problem that's causing this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: please check cookie  setting in admin also browser cookie

Comment: This is happening cause your session id is not carried over for ajax request sand typically it is related to server configuration. empty cart you see cause new session id is given and this has no responding quote attached to it

Comment: I had the same issue recently, turned out I had two "frontend" cookies saved with different values. After clearing the cookies everything worked.

Comment: I had to remove my adminhtml cookie and my cookie to the live website, as they live on the same server. Watch out for subdomain.